# Execute code after the lack or eventual completion of a CSS transition

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to execute some code immediately after a CSS transition finishes. The problem is that in certain cases (not determined by me), the transition does not have to occur. How do I know when to expect a transition? I know about the `transitionrun` and `transitionstart` events and I tried to use them, but they don't do the job:

```js
function animateIn (elem, action) {
  var expecting = false

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout', expecting)
  }, 0)

  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    console.log('raf', expecting)
  })

  elem.addEventListener('transitionrun', () => {
    expecting = true
    console.log('transitionrun')
  })

  elem.addEventListener('transitionstart', () => {
    expecting = true
    console.log('transitionstart')
  })

  elem.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    console.log('transitionend')
  })
  
  action()
}

var elem = document.getElementById('main')
elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  animateIn(elem, () => {
    elem.classList.remove('is-enter')
  })
})
```

```css
#main {
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

#main.is-enter {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="is-enter"></div>
```

As you can see, I want to use the `expecting` variable to check whether a transition will start after whatever happens in the `action` function. And that's what I basically want - to check if a certain action (the removal of a class in this case) causes a transition to run.

My idea was to use `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` to wait for a little bit and if `transitionrun` or `transitionstart` has fired in the meantime - then a transition is expected, otherwise - it's not.

The problem with that is the fact that both `requestAnimationFrame` and `setTimeout` run *before* `transitionrun` and `transitionstart` had the chance to fire (at least in Chrome). So it appears that the transition takes longer to start than one render loop? Why is that?

One workaround is to use an arbitrary timeout that gives the transition enough time to eventually start:

```js
function checkTransition (elem, action) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    var willTransition = false
    var startHandler = function () {
      willTransition = true
      elem.addEventListener('transitionend', function endHandler () {
        elem.removeEventListener('transitionend', endHandler)
        resolve(true)
      })
    }
    
    elem.addEventListener('transitionstart', startHandler)
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.removeEventListener('transitionstart', startHandler)
      if (!willTransition) {
        resolve(false)
      }
    }, 100)
    
    action()
  })
}

var elem = document.getElementById('main')
elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  checkTransition(elem, () => {
    elem.classList.remove('is-enter')
  }).then(status => {
    console.log('had transition:', status)
  })
})
```

```css
#main {
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

#main.is-enter {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="is-enter"></div>
```

When you click the box for the first time, the Promise waits for the transition to finish and resolves with `true` to signal that a transition has happened. If you click it more times after that, it resolves with `false` because no transition occurred. That's exactly what I need.

The problem is `setTimeout`. That 100ms wait is completely arbitrary and very error-prone, I suppose. Is there a better way to capture this? I need some sort of way to fire code immediately after a `transitionstart` *might* occur. I was hoping that `requestAnimationFrame` would do this but it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work in Chrome (latest), Firefox (latest) and IE11 with a double `requestAnimationFrame`, even for delayed transitions:

```js
function checkTransition (elem, action) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    var willTransition = false
    var startHandler = function () {
      willTransition = true
      elem.addEventListener('transitionend', function endHandler () {
        elem.removeEventListener('transitionend', endHandler)
        resolve(true)
      })
    }
    
    elem.addEventListener('transitionrun', startHandler)
    elem.addEventListener('transitionstart', startHandler)
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        elem.removeEventListener('transitionrun', startHandler)
        elem.removeEventListener('transitionstart', startHandler)
        if (!willTransition) {
          resolve(false)
        }
      })
    })
    
    action()
  })
}

function bind (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    checkTransition(elem, () => {
      elem.classList.remove('is-enter')
    }).then(status => {
      console.log('had transition:', status)
    })
  })
}

bind(document.getElementById('main'))
bind(document.getElementById('delayed'))
```

```css
.target {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.target.is-enter {
  background: blue;
}

#main {
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

#delayed {
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="target is-enter"></div>
<div id="delayed" class="target is-enter"></div>
```

I think it's far better than an arbitrary timeout but I still have doubts whether it's reliable. To answer that, I think we need to answer first why one `requestAnimationFrame` call is not enough in Chrome.

**Edit:** This trick doesn't seem to work in Chrome on mobile.